# Environment issue with Angular2 typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, environment

Environment issue with Angular2 typescript.

I can't get angular2 project to run.
Typescript compiler has no errors.

There's only errors in the browser console.

**Heres my error console:**

[image]

**Heres my index.html:**

[image]

Comment: check that the requests for .js files are actually returning js files. It could be returning a 404 error .. or other bit of html for some reason. Try to go to the *.js url and see what's getting returned

Comment: Hi sirrocco I checked the js files and they all have the html index markup in them instead of js. Angular2.dev.js has html index in it

Comment: Are there any files I can share with you to help you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue.

I wasnt point my live-server to the correct location.
Basically, I was too deep so it couldnt reference the node modes.

**This change also had to be made to my index.html:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <base href="/"></base>
     <title>Angular</title>

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-aUGj/X2zp5rLCbBxumKTCw2Z50WgIr1vs/PFN4praOTvYXWlVyh2UtNUU0KAUhAX" crossorigin="anonymous">

     <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.18.4/system.src.js"></script>    

     <script>
         System.config({
             transpiler: 'typescript',
             defaultJSExtensions: true
         });
     </script>

     <!--<script src="angular2.dev.js"></script>
     <script src="router.dev.js"></script>
     <script src="http.js"></script>
     <script src="firebase/firebase.js"></script>-->  

     <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
     <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
     <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.js"></script>
     <script src="/src/firebase/firebaseNew.js"></script>  

   </head>

   <body class="container">
     <app></app>
     <script>
       /*System.import('app/app');*/
       System.import('src/app/app');
     </script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

I've commented out what used to be in the index.html.

I now point my live-server like this using git bash: live-server --entry-file=src/index.html